# Set selection to contents of summernote

Tags: javascript, summernote

I would like to create a button that selects the text that has been entered within the summernote editor box. The result would be as though the user had pressed ctrl+A while within the editor. I have managed to create a button that selects a plain textbox outside of summernote. Here is my code which shows both my attempt at the summernote selection and the plain textbox selection (Hello World):

```js
$('#summernote').summernote({
  height: 140,
  disableDragAndDrop: true,
  followingToolbar: true,
});

function selectText() {
  const input = document.getElementById('text-box');
  input.focus();
  input.select();
};

function selectText2() {
  const input = document.getElementById('summernote');
  input.focus();
  input.select();
};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Email Composer</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-beta.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="text-box" size="20" value="Hello world!">
  <button onclick="selectText()">Select Hello world</button><br>
  <button onclick="selectText2()">Select Summernote</button>

  <div class="summernote" id="summernote" style="width: 100%"></div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-beta.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the function **selectText2()** with this one. I hope I have been helpful.

```
function selectText2() {
    var selectText = document.getElementsByClassName("note-editable");
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(selectText[0]);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
};
```

**Preview:**

```js
$('#summernote').summernote({
    height: 140,
    disableDragAndDrop: true,
    followingToolbar: true,
});

function selectText() {
    const input = document.getElementById('text-box');
    input.focus();
    input.select();
};

function selectText2() {
    var selectText = document.getElementsByClassName("note-editable");
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(selectText[0]);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Email Composer</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-beta.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="text-box" size="20" value="Hello world!">
  <button onclick="selectText()">Select Hello world</button><br>
  <button onclick="selectText2()">Select Summernote</button>

  <div class="summernote" id="summernote" style="width: 100%"></div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-beta.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. The button needs to highlight the text just as the "Select Hello world" does.

Comment: Summernote is "div" is not "input". In your example there is no text in it. I can't figure out what the button should select?

Comment: It should select whatever the user has typed in to the summernote editor.

Comment: So close! It works but it will only select the pre-populated text (if you put something between the summernote div tags). If you change the text in the editor then nothing happens when you click the button. Thank you